# how to store output of command runing on remote computer's CMD using WMI in .net?

Tags: c#, cmd, wmi

I can connect to the remote computer using **WMI** . I want to run some commands in the remote computer's cmd and then uses these outputs in code. first I can run cmd commands but i can't access to the outputs. can I see them on the local machine?
because of this problem, I try to store output into the file on remote machine and then read that file from local machine. but it seems can't be done.
I know there are some other tools instead of WMI but i want to know that I can store outputs of cmd commands in a variable using WMI or not?

This code saves output of cmd commands in the tmp_dr.txt and then tries to access to the path which tmp_dr.txt is existed but exception occures which is **The given path's format is not supported.** when I user C$ instead c: another exception comes : **the user name or password is incorrect.** However I connect to remote pc successfully and tmp_dr.txt is created.

```cs
            ip = "172.17.9.2";
            username = "FB\\****";
            password = "****";
            port = 22;
            //    var processToRun = new[] { "cmd.exe" };
            var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            connection.Username = username;
            connection.Password = password;
            var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", "FB"), connection);
            var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
             try
            {
                 ManagementBaseObject inParams =               wmiProcess.GetMethodParameters("Create");
                 inParams["CommandLine"] = "cmd /c ls > c:\\tmp_dr.txt";
                 inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"c:\windows\system32";
                 var result = wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
                 FileStream sr = new     FileStream(@"\\FB\c:\tmp_dr.txt",FileMode.Open);
                 string line = sr.Read()         
            }
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/328461/how-to-access-c-share-in-a-network

Comment: `c:` is not a valid share name. You seem to be looking for `C$`.

Comment: @CodeCaster when I use C$ exception comes :  "The user name or password is incorrect" but I can see that I connect to the remote computer and tmp_dr.txt is created.

Comment: @CodeCaster how can I know C$ is exactly which path?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question.

Comment: @CodeCaster assume that  I want to check if file is created in C$ or not in remote pc. in which directory and folders I should search(for example c:/users/.../)

Comment: I still don't understand the question. C$ is the name of the hidden share that exposes a machine's C drive.